# Best practice to modify or customize third party theme in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, custom-theme, customization

I want to remove the block from the currently applied third-party theme.

What is the standard way to achieve this in Magento 2??

Please provide the guidelines considering the future Magento upgrade activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a block from the currently applied third-party theme in Magento 2, you should follow these guidelines:

1. First, locate the block that you want to remove in the theme files. It should be located in the theme's layout folder.
2. Copy the file to your own theme or create a custom module. Do not modify the original theme files directly as this could cause issues during future upgrades.
3. Open the copied file and remove the code that generates the block.
4. Finally, clear the cache and test the changes to ensure that the block has been successfully removed.

When making changes to your theme or creating a custom module, it's important to follow best practices to ensure future Magento upgrades are smooth and easy. Avoid modifying core files and instead create a separate module or override files in your own theme. This will make it easier to maintain your code and upgrade to new versions of Magento without running into compatibility issues.